# jquery По очереди скрывать изображении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть 2 изображения как сделать так чтобы по очереди скрывалось при прокрутке вниз на 100px.

```js
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>100)
     {
        $('img').eq(0).fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('img').eq(0).fadeIn();
     }
 });
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5ba9dd877c8a4bc5995b2101908ae648/?default=&s=80" width="200">
       <br>
<img src="http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/As_Logo_08.png" width="200">
```

Comment: Что значит "по очереди"? Используется только одно, которое вроде корректно скрывается.

Comment: То есть когда прокрутка на 100px скрывается первое изображение еще на 100px 2рое изображение.

Comment: Ну сделайте 2 `if` - 100 и 200 смещение.

Comment: А подумайте если будет 100 изображения на каждом всё это менять ?

Comment: В вопросе конкретно задано - 2. Если бы "есть N изображений" - это совсем другое дело.
Делите текущий скролл на 100, берите целое - это будет порядковый номер изображения.

Comment: Если не сложно можете дать пример хотябы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42387/discussion-between-other-and-sauron).